# Is there any way to make a spinner to delay showing its content until a certain condition happens?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I'd like to achieve the following behaviour:

1. When an spinner is touched it makes an http post that returns some results.
2. Until the results are received the spinner doesn't display showing its current results.
3. Once the results are received it finally displays showing the results.

I successfully manage to make the petition and getting the results problem is that it looks like when an spinner is touched it automatically displays. There seems to be no way of telling it: "I have now touched you, stop there, and when response is received then show the results that you have received."

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since every time user touch spinner you made a request, what you could do is , as user touch spinner , clear the values in adapter.

```
//Here is a list of options to use in spinner.
List<String> options;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context , R.layout.simple_spinner_items , options);
```

as user touch the spinner clear adapter items or if you using custom Adapter implement clear functionality or if the custom adapter inherits ArrayAdapter then no need to implement clear functionality ,its already there.

```
adapter.clear();
```

once you received the data which is List of String (I'm assuming)

```
adapter.addAll(options);
```